# Error when installing Automapper 8.1.1 with package manager in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, package-managers

I used the package manager in VS Code to install the latest version of automapper. I was on 8.0.1 and now I want to update to 8.1.1

> AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection -Version 8.1.1

And I received this message in the Omnisharp log when VS Code tried to install it and can't start the project now.

> Queue project update for '/Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj'
> info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
> Loading project: /Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj
> Can't find custom attr constructor image: /Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/Infrastructure/bin/Debug/net5.0/Infrastructure.dll mtoken: 0x0a000001 due to: Cannot resolve dependency to assembly because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.
> Can't find custom attr constructor image: /Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/Core/bin/Debug/net5.0/Core.dll mtoken: 0x0a000001 due to: Cannot resolve dependency to assembly because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.
> info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
> Successfully loaded project file '/Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj'.
> info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
> Update project: API
> Can't find custom attr constructor image: /Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/Infrastructure/bin/Debug/net5.0/Infrastructure.dll mtoken: 0x0a000001 due to: Cannot resolve dependency to assembly because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.
> Can't find custom attr constructor image: /Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/Core/bin/Debug/net5.0/Core.dll mtoken: 0x0a000001 due to: Cannot resolve dependency to assembly because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.
> [warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.PackageDependencyChecker
> API: Found package reference 'AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection', but none of the versions in the lock file ("8.0.1") satisfy [8.1.1, )
> info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
> Queue project update for '/Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj'
> info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
> Queue project update for '/Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj'
> info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
> Loading project: /Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj
> [warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
> Package 'AutoMapper 10.1.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
> [warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
> Package 'AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 8.1.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
> Package 'AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 8.1.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
> Package 'AutoMapper 10.1.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
> [warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
> Failed to load project file '/Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj'.
> /Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj
> /Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj(0,0): Error: Package 'AutoMapper 10.1.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
> /Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj(0,0): Error: Package 'AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 8.1.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: ExplicitDistrust: The trust setting for this policy was set to Deny.
> /Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj(0,0): Error: Package 'AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 8.1.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
> /Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/API/API.csproj(0,0): Error: Package 'AutoMapper 10.1.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
> info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
> Update project: API
> [warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.PackageDependencyChecker
> API: Did not find 'AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection' in lock file.

Comment: did You run npm install before npm update?
if using the nuget version dit you install it using dotnet add package command??

Comment: Hi T. I did it from the command pallete in VS Code. cmd+shift+p , then nuget package manager add package. I searched then for automapper and clicked on the version.

Answer (score 0):

this should work off the bat without, but did you try a dotnet restore before dotnet build? then if that didn't try building with the verbose set to detailed.

```
dotnet build -v d
```

to see more explicitly what is missing, then make sure to add that first.

if your you have a project.lock.json file, try deleting it and execute

```
dotnet restore
```

this should recreate your apparently out of sync lock file

Also you could be suffering from an SDK bug https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6595#issuecomment-905086918 in which case you need to update to 5.0.4 or above

Comment: Hi T. I tried both both can't do a build or restore after adding the 8.1.1 library from the 8.0.1 package. I see an error saying "Package 'AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 8.1.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired. [/Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/yogabandy2020.sln]" and "The repository primary signature validity period has expired. [/Users/charlespareto/yogabandy2020/yogabandy2020.sln]"

Comment: I found a bug with that issue and updated suggestions with an item more, looks like a bug which is a couple of months old and you may need to update Your SDK to fix it